# npm install cypress failing on M2 MacBook Air since 5/25/23

Tags: npm, cypress, npm-install

The project that i am collaborating on requires cypress in the npm install. The project is an ionic/react project/. For some reason, since about 5/25/23, every time I try to run an npm install on my project it fails with the following error code. I have tried the recomeneded steps on sevreal websites to no avail. Can anyone help with this please?

> npm ERR! The Cypress App could not be downloaded. npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> Does your workplace require a proxy to be used to access the Internet?
> If so, you must configure the HTTP_PROXY environment variable before
> downloading Cypress. Read more:
> https://on.cypress.io/proxy-configuration npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> Otherwise, please check network connectivity and try again: npm ERR!
> npm ERR! ---------- npm ERR!  npm ERR! URL:
> https://download.cypress.io/desktop/12.13.0?platform=darwin&arch=arm64
> npm ERR! Error: Corrupted download npm ERR!  npm ERR! Expected
> downloaded file to have checksum:
> fa02be5891fb9ae5039aaf7f0a84b64a584ac21b26d4371ced6fcdfcea3c9dce7dd026bef463e66cc8be47d0b84f69ea7a67d118f1f23d53e80887bf6f5a4377
> npm ERR! Computed checksum:
> 286dd362916dc8835ee6e94eaf3859ba3dafb07d5701f815fe9170b529fa6b4a82fcfc3c0c3c1ada525823060eb965956c0b70acfc05bac97d373399e915fea4
> npm ERR!  npm ERR! Expected downloaded file to have size: 156475281
> npm ERR! Computed size: 7502126 npm ERR!  npm ERR! ---------- npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Platform: darwin-arm64 (22.5.0) npm ERR! Cypress Version:
> 12.13.0 npm ERR! [FAILED] The Cypress App could not be downloaded. npm ERR! [FAILED]  npm ERR! [FAILED] Does your workplace require a proxy
> to be used to access the Internet? If so, you must configure the
> HTTP_PROXY environment variable before downloading Cypress. Read more:
> https://on.cypress.io/proxy-configuration npm ERR! [FAILED]  npm ERR!
> [FAILED] Otherwise, please check network connectivity and try again:

I have tried

```
npm cache clean --force

npm uninstall cypress

npm uninstall cypress && npm install cypress
```